# Why is A-stability and L-stability tested on exponentials?

Tags: numerical-methods, definition, stability-in-odes

Is there a reason why stability of numerical methods is tested on exponentials functions? Can such concept be generalized for other functions? I mean how does testing stability on functions $f(x) = e^{\alpha x}$ give an indications of how more stable a method compared to another?

Is such test function like a worst case scenario?

Comment: Maybe it is because, locally, all dynamical systems look like exponentials, by linearization.

Comment: Maybe an instance would help.

Comment: I mean, the system of ODEs $\dot{x}=Ax$, where $x\in \mathbb R^n$ and $A\in \mathbb R^{n\times n}$ has the unique solution $x(t)=e^{At}x_0$, so studying exponential behavior one covers all constant coefficients linear systems. In the nonlinear case, say $\dot{x}=\Phi(x)$, for any $x_0$ we have that $\dot{x}=Ax +\Phi(x_0)-Ax_0$ (up to higher order terms), where $A$ is the Jacobian matrix of $\Phi$ at $x_0$. Thus, for $x$ close to $x_0$, the system is close to a linear constant coefficients one, so the linear stability analysis is useful somewhat.

Comment: This is just a personal digression, I am no expert in numerical methods. I had the same question years ago, though, and this is the justification I gave to myself.

Comment: Does this criterion work on PDE as well?

Comment: PDEs are much more complicated. Some of these ideas can be recovered, of course, but things are not so clear cut. Anyway, this is a digression.